# How do I get list of most popular categories within a radius?

Tags: foursquare

As the question states, I am looking to get returned a list of the most popular categories within a given area at a given time (hourly).

What I am attempting to achieve is to display a list of the current 10 "trending" categories, which would be refreshed every hour. So let's say at 6pm, one could assume that "bars" would be one of the more popular categories at the time within my given radius. It being the most popular category of that hour, I'd display it first.

Would I grab all venues within the radius and compile the data/math myself? Or is there a shortcut that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to directly get the information you're after, but there's certainly an indirect approximation possible. Take a look at [venues/trending](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/trending) for trending venues around a lat/lon, and you can extract categories from that.

Comment: Unfortunately, (even in Denver) there are few businesses that are "trending" at any given time (at least according to 4sq). I've considered using venues/trending but it wouldn't be an accurate representation of what is actually happening in the areas where we'd be using the software.